# How to restore Homebrew config from Time Machine or backup

Tags: php, backup, homebrew, restore, timemachine

TL;DR I killed my Homebrew and now need to restore from Time Machine.

I had a working Homebrew with various packages installed and working. I've installed some new packages (upgraded php 5.6 to php 7) which I no longer wanted so I removed them and tried to reinstall the old package. This is not working which I believe is due to my openssl during that process.

I have a Time Machine backup from when everything was working a few days ago. What steps are needed to restore Homebrew to that old state?

I have tried restoring `/usr/local/Cellar` directory but it appears I need to do something else (php still running the bad version).
Should I restore `/usr/local/opt`? Is there anything else?

I prefer not to do a full mac restore if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hope I am not too late, your formulae installations should be all in `/usr/local/Cellar`, and then you can run `brew doctor` to see what are the broken links that you should fix.

Worst case, you might need to reinstall some formulae, hope you are using a supported MacOS version.